# How to create load runner script for IOS mobile app from load runner machine

Tags: ios, httprequest, loadrunner

I have an IOS mobile app I want to capture the requests for IOS app from my load runner machine.

Could someone please explain how can I get the requests and responses in load runner machine.

Answer (score 0):

With an assumption of an HTTP connection architecture from the IOS application to the next upstream architectural component, the natural way to capture the requests would be to leverage either a proxy connection or a wireshark/PCAP style trace at the server from the affected client.   Take a look at the documentation related to the use of the proxy recorder for HTTP and also the documentation related to the upconversion of a PCAP trace file.  I think the best source of docs on the PCAP front is for a web services virtual user.